# How to create a nested combination of values from a list of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have the following structure:

```
$arr = array(
    array('123', '456'),
    array('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'),
    array('Test1', 'Test2'),
);
```

And I would like to create a nested combination of these values in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [Red] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
            [Blue] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
            [Green] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
        )
    [456] => Array
        (
            [Red] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
            [Blue] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
            [Green] => Array
                (
                     [Test1] => Null
                     [Test2] => Null
                )
        )
)
```

The input array can have a different number of arrays and values. The order of the elements should be respected.

How can I archive that? I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Use loop or array walk function

Comment: Is it a static structure or can you have more than 3 array in your array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: since answers have already been posted, I'll post mine. But as mentioned in the comments, you're expected to show your own attempts first. Please do that next time!*

You may use a recursive function that maps the keys of the first dimension to the result of the following one, and so on:

```
$arr = [
  ['123', '456'],
  ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
  ['Test1', 'Test2']
];

function getCombinations(array $dimensions): array
{
  $combinations = [];
  $first_dimension = reset($dimensions) ?: [];

  foreach ($first_dimension as $value) {
    $combinations[$value] = count($dimensions) > 1 
      ? getCombinations(array_slice($dimensions, 1)) 
      : null;
  }

  return $combinations;
}

print_r(getCombinations($arr));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/hEhEv**

Comment: Thank you. This is a pretty nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as an example, I didn't build any error check for the datatype. You have to use it to best fit your usage case.

For the routines to solve your problem, first, the arrays for the last index of the input array are made first. Then I have another function(makeArray), of which will make an array with two parameters, $make, and $with. makeArray, return an array with indexes bases on the string values of each array index from parameter $make. Each of the indexes of the array made with makeArray is assigned the value of the $with parameter.

After my toStructural function made the first array based on the lastIndex of the input array. Its traverse the input array from the highest index to lowest index. Each time, its call the makeArray function with two parameters, the indexes or the input array where it is currently at, and what it already have as output. That value is then assigned back to the output variable.

Think of this like building from bottom to top.

```
$arr = array(
    array('123', '456'),
    array('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'),
    array('Test1', 'Test2'),
);

function toStructural( $arr ){
    $output = [];
    $lastIndex = count($arr) - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$lastIndex]); $i++ ){
        $output[$arr[$lastIndex][$i]] = null;
    }

    for ($i = $lastIndex - 1; $i > -1; $i--){
        $output = makeArray($arr[$i],$output);
    }
    return $output;
}

function makeArray( $make, $with ){
    $output = [];
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($make); $i++ ){
        $output[$make[$i]] = $with;
    }
    return $output;
}

var_dump(toStructural($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more precised version may be help you

```
$newarray = array();

    foreach($arr[0] as $key=>$value){
        foreach($arr[1] as $key=>$value1){
            foreach($arr[2] as $key=>$value2){
                $newarray[$value][$value1][$value2] = 'Null';
            }
        }
    }
```

output will be same

```
    Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [Red] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

            [Blue] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

            [Green] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

        )

    [456] => Array
        (
            [Red] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

            [Blue] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

            [Green] => Array
                (
                    [Test1] => Null
                    [Test2] => Null
                )

        )

    )
```

Comment: Tidier without keys in your foreaches.  How would you address a variable amount of elements in the original array?